# How to add 3rd party code to android app?

Tags: android

How can I use 3rd party code, such as [this](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol) in my android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `library/` directory in that repo is an Android library project. Once you have downloaded the code (via the ZIP file, or cloning the git repo), you can add that library project to your [Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), [Ant](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), or [Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Referencing-a-Library) projects. There are ways to add it via Android Studio as well, though I am not aware of an official documentation link for that.

Once the library is available to your app, follow [the instructions on the project's home page](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol) to add it to your UI.

Comment: Do I have to update the androidmanifest.xml as well? If so, how?

Comment: @user2239690: I am not aware of your needing to update the manifest for this.